# Associate JPG with Irfanview in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-association, irfanview

For a friend I needed / tried to change the default file association with "jpg":

- I tried the standard "search on associate" / "associate with program" choose jpg then select d:\program\irfanview.exe BUT... it keeps jumping back to the default Windows image viewer
- I then tried Total Commander "associate with" (AS Adminstrator) and via the file extension set irfanview as the default viewer. The confusing thing here: although the total commander list box shows me irfanview as the associated application for jpg... the "associate with program" box of windows.... shows the ms picture viewer.... (and it still opens with ms picture viewer). (ps via Total Commander is probably the same as with the countless associate-with tools)
- I also tried from within Irfanview "set associated extensions" (I choose ALL image extensions jsut to be sure)
- I also tried set default programs (via control panel) but Irfanview does not appear in that list

Hmmm... why does it not let me pick d:\program\irfanview.exe as default program for jpg's in windows 8? (ps I changed all 4 occurences of "jpg" in the list with associated action "open")

**update**: I begin to assume that it has to do with Irfanview itself and Windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open control panel (desktop)->standard programs and select "set your default program"

[image]

Now pick IrfanView and and choose which file types you want to associate.

Comment: tried that as the first thing: there is no irfanview in the list. thats why i went for "associate a file type or protocol with a program"

Comment: I also tried it from within irfanview "set file extension associated" ... AND I ran all the stuff as administrator.

Comment: reinstall IrfanView. I see it in the list: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/irfanView.png

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a file type you want to associate with Irfanview.
From the menu that appears chose open with.
In the list of programs that appear choose Irfanviw.
Make sure the little tick box at the top of the page is ticked (it says always open this type of file with this program) then finish.

It has to be done for every file type.